# Ionicons not showing anymore when switching to @IonicPage components

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionicons

After changing my pages to be lazy loaded (via @IonicPage with separate modules) all ionicons dissapeared. When declaring the components directly in app.module.ts, everything works fine.

I did find a [workaround using web components](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionicons/issues/499), but it's pretty cumbersome and I still think this is either a bug or I did not know how to import the proper module or didn't create the structure as it was supposed to.

This is how I use the ionicons:

```
 <button [navPush]="'admin'" ion-button icon-end>
        Admin
        <ion-icon name="star"></ion-icon>
 </button>
```

- Broken version: https://github.com/ScaleIT-Org/ionic-app-skeleton/tree/ionicon-broken
- "No lazy load" working version: https://github.com/ScaleIT-Org/ionic-app-skeleton/tree/ionicon-fix-no-lazy-load
- Fixed (workaround #499) version: https://github.com/ScaleIT-Org/ionic-app-skeleton/tree/ionicon-workaround-fix

How it should look like:
[image: Icon is visible (no lazy loaded pages)]

Icon not visible anymore after switching to separate modules and @IonicPage Component:
[image: Icon is not visible (lazy loaded pages)]

I also created an issue with all the details:
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionicons/issues/526

**My question is:** Do we need to explicitly import the ionicons as a module in the code? If so, how can I do that.

Any help much appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import IonicModule in any component modules that uses Ionic components, not with the forRoot(), but simply importing IonicModule.

Update your **components.module.ts** file as follows:

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { IonicModule } from "ionic-angular";
import { AppFooterComponent } from './app-footer/app-footer';
import { AppHeaderComponent } from './app-header/app-header';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppFooterComponent,
    AppHeaderComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    AppFooterComponent,
    AppHeaderComponent
  ]
})
export class ComponentsModule {}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out and come back shortly with feedback

Comment: Awesome !! Works! Thank you

Comment: I have the same issue, i tried this, but not working !